# In SQL Server would misc pages be pushed out when an object grows within a mixed extent?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, physical-design

In SQL Server 2008-2012, objects (including tables) are first put in a mixed extent. An extent can accommodate up to 8 pages and accommodates more than one type of page (meaning: pages from more than one object). Say ExtentA has pages from objects A(2), B(2) and C(4) - numbers in parentheses indicate how many pages they own within that extent. Object B grows, and my question is: Would SQL Server start kicking out A and C's pages before assigning B a new, uniform extent (assuming it eventually outgrows extentA) OR it just jumps to a new extent given extentA is already full.

Comment: Valid question, but why do you ask? Seems to be totally unimportant knowledge.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I'm actually in a very difficult database optimization situation in which I have to crack down on unnecessary spaces being allocated for numerous tables (1000+ tables). So I'm starting from the basics... I couldn't figure out this question because I had no means of tracking it.. I can see that a new extent is being assigned, but I cannot find out whether the previous extent was fully used...

Comment: Try asking on dba.stackexchange.   This is not a programming question and is off topic for SO.

Comment: Suggestion: Delete this question and reask on DBA. The close vote count is probably not going to reach 5 meaning that this question will not be moved for you. Please leave a link to the new question as a comment here before deleting. Also include my comment and yours in the new question so that people treat this esoteric question seriously.

Comment: Question now moved to: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/96691/in-sql-server-would-misc-pages-be-pushed-out-when-an-object-grows-within-a-mixed